# urllib with twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, urllib

I am very new to python and I am trying to connect to the twitter api using urllib. I would just like to know if I am passing the correct variables to headers as I am getting 401 Authorization Required, but when passing the same params to twitter using Postman I am not having any issues.

```
headers = { 
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201', 
'Authorization':
'OAuth oauth_consumer_key = consumer_key, 
    oauth_token = token, 
    oauth_signature_method = HMAC-SHA1, 
    oauth_timestamp = timestamp, 
    oauth_nonce = nonce, 
    oauth_version = 1.0, 
    oauth_signature = signiture'
}
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I usually experiment with Curl or the requests library before going to urllib. IMHO, requests is the way to go.

Also, https://github.com/bear/python-twitter is an option for a library that takes care of the twitter auth. Use it as a reference to implement, or use it instead of creating your own.